# Bought used computer with working GSM card

Tags: wireless, gsm, simcard

I recently bought a used computer from a company. They are buying lots of computers from big companies and they refurbish them for resale. Today I discovered that my computer has an installed SIM card. This SIM card is roaming with excellent speed. I know it's bad to use this card, but I wonder: Is it easy to get caught using this connection? Can the card's real owner track my connection and location? Any good way to hide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember, SIM is "subscriber identity module."  It identifies itself to the mobile carrier each time it talks to a cell site, and the carrier knows *which* cell site.

The best you can hope for is that it will stop working when the original owner gets the next bill.  At worst, you could be tracked down with a cell site simulator (aka "stingray") and charged with theft of services.  There may be consequences in between.

Comment: Thanks. Okey. I have just tested the connection and after this information I will pull it out of my computer.